# Chrome on Mac: Annoying floating window

Tags: mac, google-chrome

Recently I see a floating window when using Google Chrome on Mac. I can't close it. It appears on top of any web page. When I right click on the Window, there's a menu shown as below:

[image]

Would you please tell me how to hide this window? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of chrome are you using?

Comment: @DManokhin: the latest one: Version 70.0.3538.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Have you tried restarting chrome? And if so with what result?

Comment: @DManokhin: I tried. But this issue happens all over again

Answer (score 1):

Closing and reopening Chrome eliminated a un-clickable floating window on my mac.

The window was floating over most other windows on a 2nd monitor and was quite large.  I was able to create a third desktop with the "show desktop" function, then drag my working windows to the new desktop (including the windows hidden behind the unclickable image) then I destroyed the crippled desktop by clicking on the X in the 'show desktop' header.  However, a small unclickable image (with the same graphic as the problem window) remained hovering on the newly populated desktop.

I closed Chrome, and the image went away.  It did not return when I reopened chrome and recovered my history.

This was Chrome Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit) on macOS Mojave 10.14.6 on 2020-02-12.

Comment: I decided to switch over Firefox. It works great!